# Doxygen - latex issue

Tags: latex, doxygen

I need some hel regarding doxygen. I have a c++ code and i want to generate the pdf documentation using doxygen. The problem is that doxygen runs, produces the html output as expected, but the refman.tex file isnt generated (it generates the "d" folders and the doxygen.sty file). I have activated the "GENERATE_LATEX" option on the configuration file and there is no visible error on the console...

Im running doxygen 1.8.1.2 on ubuntu  12.10 x64 and i have texlive 2012/Debian (latest available).

Any help will be very much appreciated.